# Como hacer que ejecute un click sobre un el elemento de la pagina

Tags: jquery, html5

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="cargaFency">Info</button><div class="card" id="card">
  <a data-fancybox href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sI_Ps7JSEk">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/_sI_Ps7JSEk/mqdefault.jpg" />
  </a>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Direct link to YouTube</p>
  </div>
```

```
 $("#cargaFency").click(function() {

    $('#card').click();

});
```

lo que necesito es que al darle click sobre el botón info se ejecute en fencybox como si le estuviera dando el clic con el el mouse

Comment: Estás haciendo click en el div, no debería ser en el link?

Comment: lo que quiero es que al hacer clic sobre el botón info que tiene id cargaFency se ejecute el fencybox y se ejecute un video, pero no como se deberia de hacer para que funcione, la parte de codigo que puse es como lo he intentado, voy a probar como me recomiendas, gracias...

Answer (score 2):

El método que estas buscando es `.on()` y el `.click()`, aunque te funcionará mejor si utilizas a través del objeto `fancybox`
Para utilizar este método le agregas un identificador a tu etiqueta y con jQuery harías lo siguiente:

```
$( "#cargaFency" ).on( "click", function() {
  $('#card').fancybox({
            'autoScale': true,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'speedIn': 500,
            'speedOut': 300,
            'autoDimensions': true,
            'centerOnScroll': true // remove the trailing comma!!
        }).click();
});
```

[Revisa este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094233/open-fancybox-from-function)

[y esta documentacion de JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094233/open-fancybox-from-function)

Comment: muchas gracias funciono a la perfección.

Comment: Si te funciona, no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta ✅:D

Comment: con tu recomendación quedo asi y me funciono $("#cargaFency").click(function() {

  $('.card-img-top').click();

});

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas es la función trigger:

```
$("#cargaFency").click(function() {
    $('#card').trigger('click');
});
```

De esta manera cuando se haga click en #cargaFency realizará el click en #card.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cargaFency").click(function() {

  $('.card-img-top').click();

});
```

siguiendo algunas recomendaciones logré resolverlo así